# Doctrine rewrites relationship with eager fetching value after findBy

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a simple entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="...\Repository\UserTestRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", uniqueConstraints={
 *     @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="U_email", columns={"email"})
 * })
 * @UniqueEntity("email", message="Email is already used!")
 */
class UserTest
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $jobTitle;

    /**
     * @var Company
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="...\Entity\Company", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $company;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getJobTitle()
    {
        return $this->jobTitle;
    }

    public function setJobTitle($jobTitle)
    {
        $this->jobTitle = $jobTitle;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setCompany(...\Entity\Company $company = null)
    {
        $this->company = $company;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }
}
```

and controller

```
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('..\Entity\UserTest');

$user = $repo->find(519);
dump($user);

$user->setJobTitle('new value');
$user->setCompany(null);
dump($user);

$repo->findBy(['email' => 'test@test.com']);
dump($user);
```

[image: 1-st dump, original]

[image: 2-nd dump, after changes without flush]

[image: 3-rd dump, after findBy, jobTitle - with new value, company - original value, changes were lost]

1-st dump, original

2-nd dump, after changes without flush

3-rd dump, after findBy, jobTitle - with new value, company - original value, changes were lost

Is it normal doctrine behaviour or is it a bug? I use doctrine/orm v2.5.11. Was it fixed in newer versions?

Any help, pls

Comment: wow. that's really weird and unexpected behaviour.

Comment: as far as i can tell, it's not fixed in newer versions. I don't know, if it's bug or normal behaviour... anyway, you could just open an issue on github, to find out, or ask in discord or whatever

Comment: I would assume, any findBy that actually hits the database will rehydrate the objects. since doctrine promises to always return the same object, it is in an impossible situation. on one hand, you requested the results of a query, on the other hand, you made changes to the object.

Comment: when you set a different company, and not `null` it actually works as you would expect.

Comment: yes, for non null values it works correct

Comment: so I would agree with you, that this *seems* to be a bug, since it's *inconsistent*. I posted the link to this question to doctrine slack.

Comment: okay, looks like there is an issue that is related: https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7458 the linked test case is very very similar to your code.

Answer (score 1):

It's Doctrine normal behaviour when looking for unflushed entity through repository's findBy(). Please refer to https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/5092 to get more info.